# Show continuity or uniform continuity of $\phi: (C([0,1];\Bbb R ),||\cdot||_\infty )\to (\Bbb R, |\cdot | )$

Tags: analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

$\phi: (C([0,1];\Bbb R ),||\cdot||_\infty )\to (\Bbb R, |\cdot  | ); \: \: \: \: \: \:  \phi(u):=\int_0^1 u^2(t) dt $

Is this function continuous or even uniformly continuous? (I know that the function $g: M\to \Bbb R , g(x) := x^2$ is continuous but not uniformly)

Also, is there a non-empty subset of $ C([0,1];\Bbb R )$ so that $\phi$ is Lipschitz-continuous on that set?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\phi$ will be continuous. Indeed, fix any $u\in C_{[0,1],\mathbb{R}}$, and let $\delta > 0$ such that $\delta(2\lVert u\rVert_\infty + \delta) \leq \varepsilon$.

Fix any $\varepsilon > 0$. If $v$ is such that $\lVert u - v\rVert_\infty \leq \delta$, then
$$\begin{align}
\lvert \phi(u)-\phi(v) \rvert &= \left\lvert \int_{[0,1]} u^2-v^2\right\rvert 
\leq 
\int_{[0,1]} \left\lvert u^2-v^2\right\rvert 
\\
&=
\int_{[0,1]} \underbrace{\left\lvert u-v\right\rvert}_{\leq \lVert u - v\rVert_\infty} \cdot \underbrace{\left\lvert u+v\right\rvert}_{\leq 2\lVert u\rVert_\infty+\delta}
\leq \delta(2\lVert u\rVert_\infty + \delta) \leq \varepsilon
\end{align}$$
i.e. $\phi$ is continuous.

It is easy to adapt the above to show that $\phi$ will be Lipschitz (and therefore uniformly continuous) on any subset of any $C_{[0,1],[-a,a]}\subseteq C_{[0,1],\mathbb{R}}$ (i.e., for functions bounded by some universal constant). The Lipschitz constant will then be $2a$ (replacing the $2\lVert u\rVert_\infty + \delta$ term).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it enough to say that the function $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous to say that $\phi$ isn't either?

Comment: Not quite sure right now, but maybe (considering the constant functions $f_x\colon t\in [0,1]\to x$) -- I'll think about it once back.

Comment: Yes, the same proof/argument will go through. (To show non uniform continuity.)

Comment: Oh, my bad, your proof is already the proof for uniform continouity.

Comment: No, i prove continuity: and uniform continuity (via Lipschitz) over any subset of functions with bounded range.

Comment: @DeltaChief, the delta chosen depends on u in the proof i wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Let  $T:C[0,1]\to L^2(0,1)$, $S:L^2(0,1)\to  \mathbb{R}$ and $R:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by $$Tf=f, \ Sg=\|g\|_2, \ R(t)=t^2$$ Then $\varphi =R\circ S\circ T.$ The linear map $ T$ is  continuous as $\|f\|_2\le \|f\|_\infty.$ Also $S$ is continuous since the norm is continuous on any normed space. Thus $\varphi$ is continuous as a composition of three continuous mappings. Clearly the mapping $\varphi$ is not Lipschitz as the property fails on constant functions, as $R(t)$ is not Lipschitz.